# SwiftUI: how to make List view transparent? How to change List view background color?

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

in case of create the List with Swift UI I have uncontrollable background of the List

[image]

Looks like there is absent "native" way to change background color of List  background color.

How to make it transparent?

(Answer is below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following code makes ALL OF `List`s background color transparent:

```
// Removes background from List in SwiftUI
extension NSTableView {
    open override func viewDidMoveToWindow() {
        super.viewDidMoveToWindow()
        
        backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        enclosingScrollView!.drawsBackground = false
    }
}
```

the following code makes ALL OF `TextEditor`s background color transparent:

```
extension NSTextView {
    open override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = .clear //<<here clear
            drawsBackground = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use UITableView in Mac OS project. It gives me following error: Use of unresolved identifier 'UITableView'

Comment: Perfectly working nice extension thanks!